# Azure internal load balancer hostname?

Tags: azure, internal-load-balancer, azure-load-balancer

Does the Azure internal load balancer have a hidden hostname? I know the public one does but I thought the internal one also had one with a *.internal.cloudapp.net suffix at some point, similar to virtual machines:

```
[azureuser@bastion ~]$ hostname -f
bastion.jelt1kdogtheznzc1giioh4lrd.phx.internal.cloudapp.net
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it does not, you can use hostfiles and\or dns entries in your own dns servers to assign hostnames to internal load balancer

Comment: I think you can use Azure private dns now for this as well

Answer (score 0):

Public load balancer supports inbound and outbound scenarios so hostnames are must, while an internal load balancer directs traffic only to resources that are inside a virtual network or that use a VPN to access Azure infrastructure. In this respect, an internal load balancer differs from a public load balancer.